# Google maps marker how saved data

Tags: android, google-maps

When I paint I need to bind some data marker when the marker, and I need to click on the marker to get data. How do I bind data and received data? i need help! thanks

Comment: please add your code, so we can help what you need

Answer (score 0):

You can bind your data to a `Marker` using a `HashMap`. The key will be the `Marker` itself and the value will be the data that you need to relate to your `Marker` (just a `String` in my example):

```
private Map<Marker, String> markers = new HashMap<>(); // Map to bind a Strings to Markers

// ...

Marker marker1 = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(52, 5)));
markers.put(marker1, "One");
Marker marker2 = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(52.1, 5.1)));
markers.put(marker2, "Two");

map.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
        Log.i("Marker", markers.get(marker)); // Query the map to get the String related to the clicked Marker
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: The map itself doesn't manage well a large amount of markers. You may want to take a look at marker clustering: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/marker-clustering